# После сборки Android в эмуляторе нет интернет соединения

Tags: android, сеть, эмулятор

Я только что собрал Android из исходников, используя команду `make full_x86-eng`.

Все прошло без ошибок, но при запуске с помощью команды

```
emulator -system out/target/product/generic_x86/system.img \
  -ramdisk out/target/product/generic_x86/ramdisk.img \
  -data out/target/product/generic_x86/userdata.img -avd nexus
```

оказалось, что в эмуляторе нет доступа к сети интернет. С образами из SDK все в порядке - интернет есть. Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

```
netstat -rn                                         
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
 tcp       0      0 0.0.0.0:5555           0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
 tcp       0     95 10.0.2.15:5555         10.0.2.2:58532         ESTABLISHED

netcfg
eth0     UP                                   10.0.2.15/24  0x00001043 52:54:00:12:34:56    
sit0     DOWN                                   0.0.0.0/0   0x00000080 00:00:00:00:00:00    
lo       UP                                   127.0.0.1/8   0x00000049 00:00:00:00:00:00


ping 10.0.2.2                                        
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: вот [этот ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8191487/4827341) не читали?